I have a file name in epackage - Sell In and Sell Out - Master - NS CBEC_20240711164411.xlsx - ADF Copy activity Dynamic expression
I have a file name in epackage - Sell In and Sell Out - Master - NS CBEC_20240711164411.xlsx - while loading in Storage through Copy activity i need dynamic expression to update in Sink to reflect only eCommerce - Sell In and Sell Out - Master - CN_CBEC.xlsx without datetime stamp - i tried multiple expressions like below

@{concat(substring(item().name, 0, lastIndexOf(item().name, '_')), '.', split(item().name, '.')[1])}
@{concat(
replace(
if(equals(lastIndexOf(item().name, ''), -1),
split(item().name, '.')[0],
substring(item().name, 0, lastIndexOf(item().name, ''))
),
'-',
'_'
),
'.',
split(item().name, '.')[1]
)}
@{concat(substring(item().name, 0, lastIndexOf(item().name, '_')), '.', split(item().name, '.')[1])}

but getting error any help is appreciated
i tried multiple expressions like below

@{concat(substring(item().name, 0, lastIndexOf(item().name, '_')), '.', split(item().name, '.')[1])}
@{concat(
replace(
if(equals(lastIndexOf(item().name, ''), -1),
split(item().name, '.')[0],
substring(item().name, 0, lastIndexOf(item().name, ''))
),
'-',
'_'
),
'.',
split(item().name, '.')[1]
)}
@{concat(substring(item().name, 0, lastIndexOf(item().name, '_')), '.', split(item().name, '.')[1])}

but getting error any help is appreciated

You can try the below expression to achieve your requirement.
@{replace(concat(substring(variables('filename'), 0, lastIndexOf(variables('filename'), ' ')),'_',last(split(concat(substring(variables('filename'), 0, lastIndexOf(variables('filename'), '_')), '.', split(variables('filename'), '.')[1]),' '))),'epackage','eCommerce')}

Here, the variable filename contains your file name epackage - Sell In and Sell Out - Master - NS CBEC_20240711164411.xlsx.

Result:

If your file name is only the last part NS CBEC_20240711164411.xlsx, then you use below expression.
@{concat(split(variables('filename'),' ')[0],'_',split(split(variables('filename'),' ')[1],'_')[0],'.',split(variables('filename'),'.')[1])}


Thank you Rakesh....
my file name is epackage - Sell In and Sell Out - Master - NS CBEC_20240711164411.xlsx
expected output should be epackage - Sell In and Sell Out - Master - NS CBEC.xlsx

I have tried your first expression for this and it's working fine for me https://i.imgur.com/IWqG3Hz.png. Can you provide what error it gave to you?

and also, please provide your expression picture in the copy activity so that I can check if there is any string interpolation errors.
